# Failed to execute 'iterateNext' on 'XPathResult': The document has mutated since the result was returned

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, webdriver-io, chrome-devtools-protocol

i need help regarding iterating over elements after i $$'d an xpath.

```
// page.js
class Page {
    get allBlogPosts() {
        return $$(`xpath/a`);
    }
}
```

```
// .spec.js file
//...
const blogPosts = await page.allBlogPosts;
        await browser.pause(1000);

        for (const post of blogPosts) {
            await post.scrollIntoView();
            // do stuff...
            await browser.back();
        }
// ...
```

In the services config I was using chromedriver, and all is well. But I need to change to devtools and this is where I got this error:
`Failed to execute 'iterateNext' on 'XPathResult': The document has mutated since the result was returned.`
A simple search says that i should use the snapshotItem(i) method of XPathResult, but, I don't know how I can do this in my WebdriverIO project.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to avoid the error by waiting for one of the blog post to exist/display before getting the array of blog posts and before scrolling a post into view inside the for loop.

```
// .spec.js file
//...
await page.oneBlogPost.waitForExist();
const blogPosts = await page.allBlogPosts;
        await browser.pause(1000);

        for (const post of blogPosts) {
            await page.oneBlogPost.waitForExist();
            await post.scrollIntoView();
            // do stuff...
            await browser.back();
        }
// ...
```